# How do you add an About button to the application information page?

Tags: android

From browsing through my applications (on the manage applications),
I've noticed that my "HTC Sense"'s information page has an "About" 
button above the uninstall & force close buttons.

I wonder if I can add this button to my applications as well,
Thanks,
Eli.

looking for an android java solution, thanks.

Comment: Do u want a button that will uninstall an application after click

Comment: Google recommends not including a force close option. Why would you want to advertise an uninstall option? It's extremely rare for non-bloatware and the point of releasing an app is so that people will install it.

Comment: He is not asking for the Uninstall button. He is asking for an About button on the Information Page of the App when you go to Uninstall that App.